# How to fix "Cannot start service pgsql: b'OCI runtime create failed:" when trying to up a pgsql container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, alpine-linux

I get the following

ERROR: for marx_pgsql_1  Cannot start service pgsql: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/docker-entrypoint.sh\": permission denied": unknown'

when i try to fire up a pgsql alpine docker image.

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
  image: nginx:1.17.1-alpine
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
    - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf
  links:
    - php
php:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./code:/code
  links:
    - pgsql
pgsql:
  image: yobasystems/alpine-postgres:latest
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: bookmarx
    POSTGRES_USER: admin
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  expose:
    - "5432"
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  restart: always
```

How do we fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the script `docker-entrypoint.sh` is not executable , I suggest to do the following:

create a Dockerfile:

```
FROM yobasystems/alpine-postgres:latest
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
```

update your docker-compose:

```
pgsql:
  build: .
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: bookmarx
    POSTGRES_USER: admin
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  expose:
    - "5432"
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  restart: always
```

Comment: Thanks , Your asnwer helped to fire up the image.